# How can I keep my paint from freezing in an unheated garage?

Tags: paint, garage, winterizing, winter, freezing

This is the first winter I've had cans of paint in my garage. Many paint labels advise that paint shouldn't be allowed to freeze. There are three five-gallon buckets on the floor and around ten one-gallon cans on the bottom shelf of a wire rack. Plus wood glue and caulk and other non-freezable miscellany. I'd be inclined to discard it all if it wouldn't cost so much to replace it. But insulating and heating the garage is a huge project.

What's the best way to keep this paint from freezing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make an insulated, heated enclosure for the paint. Since the paint is already on a wire rack, just insulate the floor and enclose the bottom shelf of the rack. Use a [lizard heater](http://amzn.com/B0002DIWTG) and a [thermo-cube](http://amzn.com/B0006U2HD2).

Cut and notch OSB, rigid foam insulation and some scrap pegboard to fit on the floor below the shelf. Use scrap vinyl to make a serpentine channel on the pegboard, then lay the heater in the channel, so:

[image]

When you put another piece of pegboard on top of this, you'll have a heated, insulated floor that's safe to drag heavy buckets around on.

Position a shelf above the bottom shelf, cut and notch OSB to fit above that shelf and insulation to fit below it. Secure the insulation from the OSB side with coarse-thread drywall screws.

[image]

Cut a back panel from OSB and put two rectangles of insulation on it to fit between the shelves. Secure it to the legs of the wire rack with cable ties.

[image]

Do the same for side panels. Put some paint in there to see how good it looks.

[image]

Add another side panel and a front door that matches the back panel. Secure everything with cable ties, except on the front door, where [a pair of hook latches](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-202034212/h_d2/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10053) lets you open the door.

[image]

Hook the iguana heater up to the thermo cube and you're done.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I hang a 60W drop light on the lowest shelf and wrap the shelving with a plastic tarp. Be sure the light isn't touching the plastic tarp or anything flamable.

Comment: I would use a light cheap and easy works great in my pump house.